# Reset the numeric keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$array = array(
  1 => 'one',
  2 => 'two',
  3 => 'three',
  'row' => 'four',
  'newRow' => 'five',
);
```

I need to re-index the numeric keys - 1, 2, 3.

> > Expected Output:

```
$array = array(
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three',
  'row' => 'four',
  'newRow' => 'five',
);
```

I've tried with  `array_values`, but the string keys also gets indexed.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use a loop and check if the key is an integer, and if it is, use a counting variable to set the new key?

Comment: Not entirely sure of the end goal here - a new array of `1,2,3` (keyed `0,1,2`) ? What do you want the new array to look like

Comment: Re-reading your answer not 100% sure if this is what you want? I thought you wanted to re-index only the numeric keys of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll edit the question for the expected out.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes, i can do that, thought I could get a better answer here, which could reduce a little line of my code :)

Comment: Updated my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge` to reindex you array.

**The code:**

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'three',
    'row' => 'four',
    'newRow' => 'five',
);
$reindexed_array = array_merge($array);
var_dump($reindexed_array);
```

**The result:**

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> string(3) "one"
    [1]=> string(3) "two"
    [2]=> string(5) "three"
    ["row"]=> string(4) "four"
    ["newRow"]=> string(4) "five"
}
```

A working example you can find here: https://3v4l.org/Om72e. More information about `array_merge`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

```
        $array = array(
          1 => 'one',
          2 => 'two',
          3 => 'three',
          'row' => 'four',
          'newRow' => 'five',
        );

        $newArray = [];

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_numeric($key)) {
                $newArray[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $newArray[] = $value;
            }
        }

        var_dump($newArray);
        die();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I needed a small n sweet answer ;)